# what does this code mean?

Tags: boot

Acer Chromebook, unsure what version of Ubuntu.
When I boot up, it says "/dev/mmcblk0p12: clean, 206128/930240 files, 3608297/3715584 blocks" and then a type space. I can't type in the space, power cycling and resetting hasnt helped, and nothing in the boot menu makes any sense. any help? (I'm completely new to this and its almost brand new)

- UPDATE 1: Using Alt + F2 brings up
  "Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS ubuntu-Cyan tty2
  ubuntu-Cyan login:" then a type space. I'm able to type in it. Still unsure of what to do with this.
- UPDATE 2: Currently at a road block as the owner does not know the password. Will update asap.
- UPDATE 3: Put in the username and password and it brings me to a page that says "Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.19.0-32-generic x86_64) *Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com *Management: https:landscape.canonical.com *Support https://ubuntu.com/advantage *Introducing Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications. Receive updates to over 25,000 software packages with your Ubuntu Pro subscription. Free for personal use. https://ubuntu.com/pro Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is not enabled. 0 updates can be applied immediately. Enable ESM apps to receive additional future security updates. See https://ubuntu.com/esm or run: sudo pro status. The list of available updates is more than a week old. To check for new updates run: pseudo apt update. Last login Thu Dec 28 05:19:54 CST 2023 on tty2. ubuntu@ubuntu-Cyan:~$" and then a type space. I ran "xdg-open --help" and it wasn't very helpful, neither was --manual. I still cannot access anything pass these code screens.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150575/discussion-on-question-by-bees-what-does-this-code-mean); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.